# Opening KML Network Link in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml, kmz, kml-network-link

If it is possible to open and visualize a KML Network Link in QGIS, then what are the steps involved?

KML Network Links are described at [Google Earth Network Links Explained](http://www.gelib.com/google-earth-network-links.htm) and at [Using Network Links Effectively](https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/learn/using-network-links-effectively/#using-kml-as-a-bookmark-0):

> In the most generic sense, a KML file with a network link acts as a
> gateway into the content on your server. Your users download your KML
> file just once, but they will always see the most updated content,
> even if you updated it after they download your KML.

A KML file with a network link can be embedded within a KMZ file.

Comment: I think the short answer to your question is "no". As a matter of interest, what data are you trying to display, raster or vector? N.

Comment: Any progress with this issue? @nhopton, I for example wish to export Google Maps Engine (My Maps) via NetworkLink to import it in QGIS so I can edit everything in Google My Maps, and see the changes in QGIS with no need to keep repeating the import-export workflow