# Opening KML Network Link in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml, kml-network-link

How can I open a KML Network Link in QGIS?

I have googled this question and searched for [similar questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37165/visualizing-kmz-network-link-in-qgis) on Stack Exchange. I am not asking how to open a KMZ in QGIS.

I don't see any references to trying to open a KML Network Link in QGIS.